# Monitoring Kubernetes CronJob completion using AWS Container Insights

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks

Currently, I am not able to monitor any parameter on CronJobs (in Kubernetes) other than memory usage.  Is there a way to monitor CronJob completion/failure in AWS CloudWatch? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Cronjob completion/failure by pods status only. However if you want to verify you can check by logs also if you have enable logs from EKS dashboard which will push logs to cloud watch and check the logs of cronjobs.

Also you can do something like :

```
kubectl get jobs <job-name> -o json | jq '.status.conditions'
```

but please just keep in mind `Jobs never Failed (its Pods terminated with error doesn't mean the Jobs has Failed`

How to get notification on job failing :

https://medium.com/faun/how-to-get-notifications-when-kubernetes-cronjobs-fail-ed4ca4313e81

Comment: My use case is to get alerts on failure. Assuming my pod can be made to crash when it knows it failed to do what it is supposed to do, how do we create an alarm then?

Comment: you can use third party plugin or use `kubernetes event API`. you can use K8s API and write own code.

Comment: @LeowKahMan please checck this out : https://medium.com/faun/how-to-get-notifications-when-kubernetes-cronjobs-fail-ed4ca4313e81

Comment: if you are using promethese and grafana : https://medium.com/@tristan_96324/prometheus-k8s-cronjob-alerts-94bee7b90511

Comment: `sysdig` and `datadog` also provide the functionality to send notification when kubernetes or docker event occur.

Comment: I have Prometheus and alerts setup for on-premise clusters. On AWS side, I have already deployed CloudWatch Container Insights. If I were to deploy other monitoring tools, there would be multiple of these on the cluster then. Each of these do consume quite a bit of memory; Prometheus often using more than 2GB. Is there really nothing in AWS CloudWatch Container Insights that I can use?

Comment: @LeowKahMan if you check this both docs : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-reference-performance-entries-EKS.html & https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-reference-performance-logs-EKS.html. container insight only contained details regarding memory and cpu insingh and network. however i am not sure 100% but only contain that details.

Comment: I have been using Container Insights to monitor CPU, RAM, and crucially Pod restarts. For CronJob, all I could find is RAM parameter. :(

Comment: Is there a log group containing the info about whether a pod status is Running, Completed or OOMKilled? I cannot find it in the four log groups provided by EKS.

Comment: @syg in EKS have you enabled logging ?